# Should Fullcalendar call dateClick AND select events on a single time click?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using the following Fullcalendar libs:

```
"@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/list": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/moment": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/moment-timezone": "^4.1.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.1.0",
```

When I initially define the calendar I set the `dateClick` and `select` options to point to a function -- the same function.  a la:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(
    document.getElementById("calendar"), {
        'plugins': [
            "interaction",
            "dayGrid",
            "timeGrid",
            "bootstrap",
            "list",
            "moment",
            "momentTimezone"
        ],
        ...
        'dateClick': DateClick_and_Selection,
        'select': DateClick_and_Selection,
        ...
```

This is "working".  My question is about the events that trigger these two actions.

If I am looking at a `timeGridDay` view and click&drag to select a range of times then ONLY the `select` function is called -- this is what I expected.

If I just click one time box in the grid then BOTH `dateClick` and `select` functions are called -- not what I expected.

Honestly I can't recall if this has been happening all along or if I just noticed it.

Is this new behavior?

Is this normal?

If it is normal then I know that the contents of the `info` object passed to the functions are different for  the two events.  I know that I can create two different functions but I am currently guessing that it would be a footrace to see which one triggers first.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to deal with this?

I tried to create a fiddle but the various fullcalendar libs seem to be order sensitive and I couldn't find the right order.

Ideas?

Comment: "BOTH dateClick and select functions are called -- not what I expected."...why not? You clicked on a date. You also selected a date/time (albeit a single one, not a range...but fullCalendar will set a default end date for that). Your action triggered both events, that's all. Why you decided to make them both fire the same function, I'm not really clear about. (BTW It's not new behaviour no, it was the same in previous versions.) P.S. here's a CodePen you can fork, if you want to play with demos: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOOzjXJ

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to deal with this?"...deal with what? I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve. There are two different callbacks here. They have slightly different purposes. In certain circumstances they may both fire in response to the same stimulus. That, in itself, is not an issue. So simply...decide which one to use, and then use it. If you're unsure which one to use, please explain what you're trying to achieve, and maybe we can advise you.

Comment: Thank you! You made me think about this in a slightly different way.  So the problem is that if both function hooks are called and I want to do something with the time ranges then, at least in my case, the second event "wins".  Unfortunately, that second function call does not always have the date/time range I expect it to have.  My "solution" seems to be to not use the `dateClick` hook and only rely on the `select`.

Comment: Good idea. I can't think of many situations where you'd need both.

Answer (score 3):

The "solution", at least in my case, is to not implement BOTH `dateClick` and `select` hooks.  If both are implemented then both fire on click events (at least in Month view).  Since both are triggered then there is basically a race to see which one finishes last, the date ranges associated with the last event overwrites the first one, again in my case.  Your use cases may be different.  Thanks to ADyson for helping me think through this in a clearer way.